# Default/Dynamic value on standard Object's list view

Tags: visualforce, lightning-web-components, list-view

I have created a new List View 'Opportunity on Region' and I also have custom field Region on Opportunity. Is there a way I can add filter on the 'Opportunity on Region' list view dynamically upon load? It will be based from the Region on where the User is.

Answer (score 0):

So, you need to do two things

- Create a custom formula checkbox field on the Opportunity called `Is_Running_User_Region_Same_As_Region__c` with formula expression:

  ```
   Region = $User.Region__c
  ```
- Then, change the listView filter to include:

  `Is_Running_User_Region_Same_as_Region__c = TRUE`

The SFDC query engine will then retrieve only records that match the running user's Region